# Why does the errno in node-webkit differ from Node.js?

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

Run the same code in node-webkit and Node.js

```
var fs = require('fs')
// var fs = process.mainModule.exports.fs // node-webkit

fs.readFile('/xxxx/xx','utf-8', function (e) {
    console.log(e)
})
```

In Node.js, the errno is 34

```
{ [Error: ENOENT, open '/xxxxx/xx'] errno: 34, code: 'ENOENT', path: '/xxxxx/xx' }
```

In node-webkit, it's -2

```
{"errno":-2,"code":"ENOENT","path":"/xxxx/xx"}
```

Why the errnos are different?

Is there a errno cheat sheet for node-webkit like [this one](https://github.com/rvagg/node-errno) for Node.js?

Comment: node-webkit seems to use 'fs-extra' instead of 'fs' (a superset of fs) ... I can't see any difference in the error handling though. https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra

Comment: With Node.js v0.12.7 on Linux, your code reports errno of -2 as well. On Windows, it reports errno of -4058. It used to be 34 on both platforms in Node v0.10.x. I don't know why this has been changed either, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same error and its due to using a relative path. Try to reading fro xx directly, not from /xxxx/xx

Hope it solves it